# Maven - Nexus: find dependent projects

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-2, nexus

Is there a way in nexus to find all the projects that depend on a particular dependency?

We have a list of projects in our nexus repository. We'd need to find all the projects that use a particular dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Artifact Usage Nexus Plugin](https://github.com/saleemshafi/nexus-artifact-usage-plugin) is an open source plugin for Nexus that can do that.  A list of further available plugins and integrations is available in the [free Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/community-projects.html#_nexus_plugins).

Be sure to use the correct version of Nexus with the plugin or fork the project and update it to your version of Nexus.