# Sonatype Maven Repo: Search projects depending on project

Tags: java, maven, nexus, sonatype

Given an Sonatype Nexus™ Open Source Edition, Version: 1.9.2.4, 
I want to query for all projects, which are depending on a given project.

We have access to the Nexus-Webfrontend, but we are missing the correct syntax / documentation for the syntax.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498313/maven-nexus-find-dependent-projects.

Comment: Indeed - I'm sorry i didn't found that one. What should I do with this question now?